# Create and drop table with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jakarta-ee, create-table

I'm having some problem to implement the methods, defined under these lines, to create a table and to drop it. When i debug the code always go to the catch blocked but the queries to create and drop the table both works fine when executed in the postgreSQL console. Any idea why i'm having these errors? or there is a restriction to do these operations using Native Query ?

Here the sourcecode :

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
      public int createTableTemporaireMesure(DashboardCriteriaBean criteria)
      {
          LOG.debug("début createTableTemporaireMesure");

          int retour = 0;

          // On supprime la table temporaire s'il existe
          dropTableTemporaireMesure();

          String queryString = "CREATE TABLE TMP_MESURE AS (select * from mesures mesure ";
          queryString += " where" + addMesureFilterOptimized(criteria).substring(4) + ")";

          LOG.debug("QueryString : " + queryString);
          Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryString);

          try {
              query.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error: " +e.getMessage());
            retour = 1;
        }

          LOG.debug("fin createTableTemporaireMesure");

          return retour;
      }

      @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
      public int dropTableTemporaireMesure()
    {
          LOG.debug("début dropTableTemporaireMesure");

          int retour = 0;

        String queryString = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TMP_MESURE";
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryString);

        try {
            query.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Erreur survenue lors de la suppresion de la table : ");
            sb.append("TMP_MESURES");
            sb.append(e.getMessage());
            LOG.error(e);
        }

        LOG.debug("fin dropTableTemporaireMesure");

        return retour;
    }
}
```

**Addition** : Exception details.

```
- Drop table
--------------

    javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

    - Create table- Table not dropped cause drop method seems to don't work
    ---------------
    [ WARN] 17:31:59 (JDBCExceptionReporter.java:logExceptions:77)
    SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P07

    [ERROR] 17:31:59 (JDBCExceptionReporter.java:logExceptions:78)
    ERROR: relation "tmp_mesure" already exists

    - Create table- Table seems to be created succesfully but SQL Error = 0
    ----------------

    Hibernate: CREATE TABLE TMP_MESURE AS (select * from mesures mesure  where ( mesure.id_mesure in (select m2.id_mesure from mesures m2 where m2.code_mesure in (130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,150,151,153,154,155,156,157,158,190,230,231,232,233,234,237,269,270,271,275,280,285,299,331,350,351,352,353,354)) or (mesure.id_mesure in (select m2.id_mesure from mesures m2 where m2.code_mesure>=100) and mesure.id_mesure in (select m2.id_mesure from mesures m2 where m2.code_mesure<200)) or (mesure.id_mesure in (select m2.id_mesure from mesures m2 where m2.code_mesure>=200) and mesure.id_mesure in (select m2.id_mesure from mesures m2 where m2.code_mesure<300)) or (mesure.id_mesure in (select m2.id_mesure from mesures m2 where m2.code_mesure>=300) and mesure.id_mesure in (select m2.id_mesure from mesures m2 where m2.code_mesure<400))))
    [ WARN] 17:37:56 (JDBCExceptionReporter.java:logExceptions:77)
    SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 02000

    [ERROR] 17:37:56 (JDBCExceptionReporter.java:logExceptions:78)
    La consulta no retornó ningún resultado. Translation **(Query doesn't returned any result)**
```

Comment: Could you provide the exception ?

Comment: Exception details added.